# How do I use Android ZoomButtonsController?

Tags: android, zooming

OK, I'm at the end of my wits.

I have no idea how to [use android.widget.ZoomButtonsController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.html). All I want is to have a zoom controls which I [show|hide|[enable|disable] zoom [in|out] buttons] for my View. I can't add it to my layout xml, and when I instantiate it in my onCreate, I can't see it on the screen.

```
View viewer = ...
ZoomButtonsController controller = new ZoomButtonsController(viewer);
controller.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that you need to call `getZoomControls()` on the `ZoomButtonsController`, then add that to your layout wherever you want the buttons to appear. You can confirm that theory by getting a snapshot of your view hierarchy with `hierarchyviewer` when the zoom controls are theoretically visible -- if they are not in your view hiearchy, then you will need to add them.

Comment: I've tried this, but when I try to add zoomControls to my RelativeLayout, I get an exception: The specified child already has a parent... zoomControls' parent appears to be a ZoomButtonsController$Container.

Comment: @Axarydax: OK. See if `getContainer()` on `ZoomButtonsController` is in your view hierarchy. If it is not, try adding that to your layout.

Comment: @Shardul: No, sorry, I have not used the zoom controls directly, only indirectly through `WebView` and `MapView`.

Comment: I've added ZoomButtonsController.getContainer() to my View, now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Axarydax: Ah, OK. That means methods like `getZoomControls()` on `MapView` probably return the container, not the actual controls themselves. I got confused by the names. Glad to hear things are working for you!