# ZoomButtonsController not working

Tags: java, android

I added the controller's container to the layout. When I try to call the controller.setVisible(true) (in the touch event), I get this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: view
>   android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container@44c1e490
>   being added, but it already has a
>   parent

Here's the code to add the controller:

```
final TextView xView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.xView);
final ZoomButtonsController controller = new ZoomButtonsController(xView );
ViewGroup zoomControlContainer = controller.getContainer();
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
layout.addView(zoomControlContainer);
controller.setAutoDismissed(true);
```

Code to handle touch event:

```
   xView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            controller.setVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If I don't add the container, controller.setVisible(true) has no effect anyways. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358691/how-do-i-use-android-zoombuttonscontroller)  I think Mark Murphy does a good job of explaining what you should do and also how you should debug this if you are still having issues.

Comment: Nick, I tried that. But I get this error when I try to add the container.


01-31 14:11:04.734: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(670): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.


And if I don't add the container and only call controller.setVisible(true), I see nothing. I strange thing I notice is: Once I call controller.setVisible(true), the onTouch doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Ok, my text view was in a scroll view and I's initializing the controller with the text view. When I initialize the controller with the scrollview instead, I see it. But the zoom controls are not clickable now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.html).

Why dont you use:

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```