# stepper from IOS to android

Tags: android, button

I have an app for iphone and I have to make it for android,I need to make a stepper,like in image,I know that I can make two buttons to increment and to decrement the value but I want to something that already exists if it exists[image]

(onclick + value++ ,onclick - value--)

Comment: I asked if there is any solution to make it,not asked someone to make it,I asked for a solution like use this button

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the ZoomButtonsController widget, it has the looks, you only have to modify the bahaviour [How do I use Android ZoomButtonsController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358691/how-do-i-use-android-zoombuttonscontroller)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant to you use case now. But I've been looking for something very similar for quite some time. [Here](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Stepper-Touch) I've found a library that implements material design and solves my use case pretty well.

Hope this helps you. or someone else.